# Size and placement of maximised popup via javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, responsive-design, popup

I'm trying to open a maximised popup via javascript. I'm using the following code:

```
window.open('./foobar.html', 'foobar', 'scrollbars=no,location=no,menuBar=no,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,width='+screen.availWidth+',height='+screen.availHeight+'');
```

It obviously works in all non-IE browsers and I get a popup that uses the full screen. In Internet Explorer (11) it depends though in which security zone the site is in. The server is in our local intranet and if I use the IP address to access the site, IE switches to "Internet" zone and the popup opens as expected.

If I use the hostname instead, IE uses the "Local intranet" zone and suddenly the placement of the popup is all wrong (a few pixels below and to the right of the upper left corner) and it is also a little bit bigger than the available screensize.

[image]

I tried using screen.height instead of screen.availHeight and I also removed all the other variables (scrollbars, location, menuBar,...), but the result didn't change.

So far, my solution has been to add the hostname to the "Trusted Sites" zone or increase the security level of the "Local intranet" zone to "Medium". Then it works like it does in other browsers.

Obviously I would like to know what is going on here. How does the javascript code above differ from zone to zone? And how would I go about opening a maximised popup window via javascript in IE without configuring any zones, sites or security levels?

Answer (score -1):

```
   var popFull = [
        'height='+screen.height,
        'width='+screen.width,
    // all other options
    ].join(',');

    var popup = window.open('./foobar.html', 'foobar', popFull); 
    popup.moveTo(0,0);
```

Comment: That doesn't work since the popup is a few pixels bigger than the screen like I mentioned. Moving it to (0,0) may also cause unwanted behavior in dualscreen setups. You can also use top=0 and left=0 in the popup options instead.

Comment: if your popup is few pixels bigger you can use
popup.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
I am not sure quite sure of dual-screens..:(